# WPF background-method to open window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a application that checks emails from an email-account via IMAP. This function is called every 5 seconds and it needs some time to work through.

```
    private void CheckForRequests()
    {
        List<string[]> mails = CollectAllMails();

        for (int i = 0; i < mails.Count; i++)
        {
            if (mails[i][0].Split('_')[0] == "request")
            {
                //INVITATION TO ME
                if (mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] == username && mails[i][0].Split('_')[3] == "request")
                {
                    DeleteMail(mails[i][0]);
                    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you accept the request from " + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1], "Invitation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes);
                    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        DeleteMail("request_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1] + "_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] + "_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[3]);
                        SendMail("request_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1] + "_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] + "_accept", "");

                        ChatWindow chat = new ChatWindow();
                        chat.ShowDialog();
                        //do open chat window
                    }
                    else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
                    {
                        DeleteMail("request_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1] + mails[i][0].Split('_')[2]);
                        SendMail("request_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1] + "_" + mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] + "_decline", "");
                    }
                }
                //ACCEPTION FROM ANOTHER DUDE
                else if (mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] != username && mails[i][0].Split('_')[3] == "accept")
                {
                    ChatWindow chat = new ChatWindow();
                    chat.ShowDialog();
                }
                //REJECTION FROM ANOTHER DUDE
                else if (mails[i][0].Split('_')[2] != username && mails[i][0].Split('_')[3] == "decline")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your invitation was declined.", "Sorry", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                }

            }
            else if (mails[i][0].Split('_')[0] == "somethingelse")
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

My loop calls this method every 5 seconds and in this time I can't write or do anything in my application. Im pretty sure that I have to use a `Thread` or `Task` to solve the problem but I didn't found out how to do this related to my case. When I call the method in a `Task` and I click Yes it crashes and says something like it has to be a `STA-Thread`... In this case I don't even want to access the GUI with the thread, I just want to check the mails and if the method found something it should do something like break from the Task and call a method (NOT from the Task).

What would be the cleanest solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you creating the thread in a timer?

Comment: I am confused by you saying you _" don't even want to access the GUI with the thread"_ - but say it crashes after you _" click Yes"_. The MessageBox is part of the GUI - so do you want this interactivity or not?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes in a `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: @PaulF I am confused too. I really just want to check the mails in the thread but do the messagebox and the rest outside the thread.

Comment: Check out BackgroudWorker class http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker/

Comment: If the API you are using for mail supports `async` / `await` (it may not), it would be a better solution than threads.

Comment: @BradleyUffner that is a little misleading as async and await are just commands to make accessing Tasks Easier and tasks are just a more user friendly wrapper around threads

Comment: @MikeT async/await has nothing to do with wrapping threads. async /await does *not* start a new thread.  If you believe that it does, then you don't really understand async / await as well as you think you do. I would recomend starting [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), as it is an extreamly informative article written by Stephen Cleary, a true expert on async/await. Also [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/12/asyncawait-faq/)

Comment: @BradleyUffner  i think you misread me because that reply has nothing to do with anything i said

Comment: @MikeT You stated that async/await just access tasks, and that tasks are just wrappers around threads.  I don't think anyone reading that could be blamed for thinking that you were stating that async/await is used to spin up work on other threads.  If I misunderstood your intended meaning, I appologize, but on review, it still seems clear.

Comment: @BradleyUffnerI said the Async and Await are Commands(though keyword would be a better term) that makes accessing tasks easier, async defines that a method returns a task, making the specific definition of the task unnesseary, though this does also have the advantage of identifying methods that can be used as tasks, await is a simplification of Task.Wait and Task.Result. and a wrapper is code that extends or enhances the behaviour of the enclosed class, this is exactly what Task does to the older System.Threading.Thread implementation

Comment: this means that any code that supports tasks is compatible with await and doesn't require any specific adaption to be used in a code that uses ASync and Await, which is why your original comment was misleading, the api doesn't need to implement async and await it needs to implements tasks, or with a little adaption Thread, and even if it doesn't the codei can implement the MultiThreading with no support in the API at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threading issue is caused by you trying to do UI stuff on a non-UI thread. You can solve this problem by using [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever you call UI stuff like this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
{
    // Your stuff here
});
```

So in your case you'd have something like this

```
void CheckForRequests()
{
    // Do stuff

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        // Open your message box
    });

    // Do more stuff

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        // Open another message box
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd go for the local dispatcher rather than the application as its possible that the applications current dispatcher is not the one the current thread needs to access ie `DispatcherObject.Dispatcher`

Answer (score 0):

Your are Right about needing to use Threads

While @Gareth is right about the need to use a dispatcher to correctly access elements across theads, i actually don't see any threading in your code, though the error message clearly proves you have attempted some.

to implement the threading you have various options

firstly you can do this directly via Tasks or the older Thread classes

this would simply be done like so

`private void CheckForRequestsAsync()=> Task.Run(()=>CheckForRequests());`

this will instantly create and start a task that will perform CheckForRequests in a separate thread freeing the GUI to continues its work on the GUI, however this is a very basic implementation and likely will need further enhancement before reliably meeting your needs

another option is to take advantage of some of the newer features in .Net and use the async keyword

if you declare CheckForRequests as `private async void CheckForRequests (object sender, EventArgs e)` then the void will be automatically be converted into a task which can be fired off by an event hander as a async task say of a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

eg

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
  timer.Elapsed += CheckForRequests; //where CheckForRequests has the async keyword
  timer.Start();
```

combine this with the dispatcher information @Gareth suggested on anything that throws a cross thread access exception and you should be ready

this would look something like this:

```
MessageBoxResult result = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    MessageBox.Show("Do you accept the request from " + mails[i][0].Split('_')[1], "Invitation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes);
);
```

Note if you use `async` with out using the `await` keyword then you will get warnings that your thread may exit before any worker threads have completed, however this is just a warning as if you aren't calling any worker threads inside your method or you don't need them to complete before exiting then there is no harm done

Finally
one of the comments suggested using DispatcherTimer rather than a Timer, i would not suggest this as every time the timer ticks, it will run your code in the GUI thread locking it just as you are already seen, the DispatcherTimer is best used when the timer heavily changes the GUI and is quick running

though if you redefined your code then you could user a DispatcherTimer by breaking out the gui element from the slow running process

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += (s,e)=>{
   if( MessageBox.Show("Do you accept the request", "Invitation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
   {
       Task.Run(()=>CheckForRequests());
   }
}
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!